# Activate the last active sheet visible

Tags: excel, vba

I currently have a workbook that contains several 'veryhidden' sheets, which only will become visible when the correct password has been entered. However, in the case that the correct password is entered, how do I write a code which activates that sheet that just has become visible, i.e. Excel needs to ignore all the 'veryhidden' ones.

I have tried the code:

```
Sub MoveNext()
On Error Resume Next
Sheets(ActiveSheet.Index + 1).Activate
If Err.Number <> 0 Then Sheets(1).Activate
End Sub
```

However, this does not work.

Comment: Do you know its name? If so, it's simple.

Comment: Could you provide the code you're using to make the sheet visible to give some more clarification? or perhaps use something like this           Dim WS As Worksheet:
    For Each WS In Sheets:
        If WS.Index <> ActiveSheet.Index And WS.Visible = xlSheetVisible Then WS.Activate:
    Next:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare Global variables in separate module

say ,

Global Const g_sPassword As String = "password"

on the next module where you need to code ,do it as below

'mention only sheets that should be visible ,other sheets will be automatically hided

Sub OpenSheet(sSheetName As String)

```
Dim shtSheetToOpen As Worksheet, shtLoopSheet As Worksheet

Set shtSheetToOpen = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sSheetName)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
shtSheetToOpen.Visible = xlSheetVisible
For Each shtLoopSheet In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    If shtLoopSheet.Name <> shtSheetToOpen.Name And shtLoopSheet.Name <> "Sheets to be visible"   Then
       shtLoopSheet.Visible = xlVeryHidden
    End If
Next shtLoopSheet
shtSheetToOpen.Activate

Set shtSheetToOpen = Nothing
Set shtLoopSheet = Nothing
```

End Sub

' then include the below code

Sub OpenSample()

Dim sUserInput As String

```
sUserInput = InputBox("Please enter password", "Password Prompt", "")

If sUserInput =  g_sPassword Then
    MsgBox "Access Granted", vbInformation, "Access"
    Call OpenSheet("Sheetsname")
    sheetname.Activate
Else
    MsgBox "Incorrect Password.Please try again", vbCritical, "Error"
End If
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

> how do I write a code which activates that sheet that just has become visible

You can store the sheet that you are unhiding in an object and then activate

For example

```
Private ws As Worksheet

Sub UnhideCode()
    '<~~ Just an example since I do not know how you are unhiding
    If pass = "OK" Then 
        Set ws = Sheet1 '<~~ Change this to the relevant sheet
        ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible
    End If
End Sub

Sub MoveNext()
    If Not ws is Nothing then ws.Activate
End Sub
```